# Trnsient simulation in multisim is a flat line, osciloscope shows good results

Tags: oscillator, simulation, spice, multisim

I'm trying to plot results of simulation of a simple Phase shift Oscillator.
The plot looks ok in oscilloscope with an interactive simulation, but when I'm running Transient or AC Sweep, I'm just getting flat lines.

What might e wrong? Am I not understanding something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kickstart it. For example, connect R1 to a voltage source providing 0V, 1V for 1 ms, then 0. In real life, powerup does that for you.

Comment: All your ground symbols are inverted logic. Show them on the bottom.  The ideal Op Amp with no input offset may not start.  Add some input offset like 1mV then it is amplified to get started  but steady state this OSC is very unstable for amplitude and loop gain critical. so long term or startup may die out. Increase gain 1% then retest to see the flaws in this design. Also R7  SHUD BE in series with Vin- , not to ground.

Comment: Try setting the maximum time period for a transient analysis to be a tiny fraction of the period of the expected sinewave. At the moment you appear to have a poor time resolution.